# Lookup Map BIT from SQL Server column to Number (1) Column of Oracle SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, lookup

I have a Packge that is getting value from SQL server Table and storing in Oracle Database table. Column Obsolete, it is Binary Column with datatype BIT in SQL Server and same Column with datatype NUMBER (1).
When I map these both column in Lookup it gives datatype mismatch error.

Error:

[image]

Comment: When selecting from SQL Server, try using `SELECT CAST(Obsolete AS TINYINT) As Obsolete` and see if that works.

Comment: It is still same, I am new to SSIS please let me know if I can share something else that would help you to figure out

Comment: After you make that change, you'll need to make sure the metadata in SSIS has updated properly, so that it's not still binary in SSIS. Without seeing your SSIS dataflow (a screenshot might help), it's not possible to explain exactly what needs to change. If you just have a source and a destination, the easiest option might be to delete the destination, and then re-add it.

Comment: Please see figure 2, and the paragraph directly before it for info on how you can inspect the datatypes of columns. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-ssis-data-types/ I expect that the Oracle datatype will be `DT_I1`, and you need to get your SQL Server datatype to be the same. You need to make sure both External and Output columns are the same datatype. Please post back whatever datatype you find for both Oracle and SQL Server